# IE8 getPrototypeOf method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo

Pretty simple:

I have code using `Object.getPrototypeOf(...)` to get the inherited classes of a Dojo Widget (just a JS object). `Object.getPrototypeOf(...)` isn't supported in IE8. I need an IE work around. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: John Resig's blog post should help: http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/

Comment: That did it. Throw this bad boy in an answer and I'll accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Jon Resig's polyfill works
http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/

I have made it even smaller

```
if (typeof Object.getPrototypeOf !== "function")
    Object.getPrototypeOf = "".__proto__ === String.prototype
        ? function (object) {
            return object.__proto__;
        }
        : function (object) {
            // May break if the constructor has been tampered with
            return object.constructor.prototype;
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Use https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim. Among other things, it supports [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim/blob/v4.5.9/README.md#shams).

Source: [ECMAScript 5 polyfills from Modernizr project](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#ecmascript-5)

Answer (score 0):

Classes created with Dojo.declared store metadata with their superclasses so you don't need to use getPrototypeOf.

I think you can get the first superclass with

```
MyClass.prototype.constructor._meta.bases[1]
```

and its prototype with

```
MyClass.prototype.constructor._meta.bases[1].prototype
```

(bases[0] seems to be the class itself)

---

Although why are you even needing to get the prototype? Its very likely you will end up reimplementing some feature that is already provided by dojo.declare