# How to test for object literal in IE8

Tags: javascript, prototype

Currently using:

```
function isObjLiteral(_obj) {
  var _test  = _obj;
  return (  typeof _obj !== 'object' || _obj === null ?
     false :  (
        (function () {
           while (!false) {
              if (  Object.getPrototypeOf( _test = Object.getPrototypeOf(_test)  ) === null) {
                 break;
              }
           }
           return Object.getPrototypeOf(_obj) === _test;
        })()
     )
  );
```

}

to test if we're using an object literal.  The problem is that IE8< cannot use `getPrototypeOf`, does anyone know an easy workaround?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919915/ie8-getprototypeof-method - it took 2 seconds with Google to find

Comment: @Ian what would be the implementation of that...I saw that, but I'm just getting an infinite loop...

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question -- are you really trying to distinguish between `{}` (an object literal) and `new Object()` (not an object literal)?

Comment: No, maybe there's an easier solution out there, I just need to know if the passed value is an object literal or not.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but I would think "typeof obj === 'object'" would be mostly sufficient for that, as you have. You could add a secondary check for arrays, since those are technically objects: "obj instanceof Array")

Comment: @apsillers: He seems to be testing for "plain object", i.e. inheriting directly from `Object.prototype` not some custom prototype. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15315694/1048572) for various implementations

Comment: @Ian: The `.constructor.prototype` workaround does not work on prototype objects.

Comment: @Bergi So you mean the `Object.getPrototypeOf( _test = Object.getPrototypeOf(_test)` part wouldn't work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improving [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919915/ie8-getprototypeof-method):

```
if (typeof Object.getPrototypeOf !== "function")
    Object.getPrototypeOf = "".__proto__ === String.prototype
      ? function (obj) {
            if (obj !== Object(obj)) throw new TypeError("object please!");
            return obj.__proto__;
        }
      : function (obj) {
            if (obj !== Object(obj)) throw new TypeError("object please!");
            // May break if the constructor has been tampered with
            var proto = obj.constructor && obj.constructor.prototype;
            if (proto === obj) { // happens on prototype objects for example
                var cons = obj.constructor;
                delete obj.constructor;
                proto = obj.constructor && obj.constructor.prototype;
                obj.constructor = cons;
            }
            // if (proto === obj) return null; // something else went wrong
            return proto;
        };
```

Haven't tested it, but it should now work even in IE8 for the most cases. Btw, it seems like your `isObjLiteral` can be simplified to

```
function isPlainObject(obj) {
    if (obj !== Object(obj)) return false;
    var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    return !!proto && !Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
}
```